# Floating point bug when writing to file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, floating-point, binary

Im not sure if Im missing something simple but the following code fails (a and b are meant to be the same):

```
a=single(2147483584)
f=fopen('test','wb');
fwrite(f,a,'int32')
fclose(f); 
f=fopen('test','rb');
b=fread(f,inf,'int32');
fclose(f)
a
b
```

with output:

```
a = 
   2.1475e+009
b =
   -2.1475e+009
```

and the following code succeeds:

```
a=single(2147483583)
f=fopen('test','wb');
fwrite(f,a,'int32')
fclose(f); 
f=fopen('test','rb');
b=fread(f,inf,'int32');
fclose(f)
a
b
```

with output:

```
a = 
   2.1475e+009
b =
   2.1475e+009
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It's very helpful to include the actual failure when describing problems.

Comment: Added output to illustrate the problem

Comment: @twerdster: why do you create `single` values and write them as `int32`, is that intentional? If it is, you might want to explicitly cast the variables

Comment: @Amro it was intentional and explicitly casting definitely works. I was just interested to know why the Matlab cast was failing and I think Mark Dickinson answered it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Matlab well, but it seems fairly clear what's happening here.  You're converting `a` to a float and then storing the result of that conversion as a 32-bit signed integer.  But the nearest single-precision IEEE 754 float to the integer `2147483584` is `2147483648.0`, or `2**31`.  A 32-bit integer can only represent values in the range `[-2**31, 2**31-1]`, so it looks as though when you write this value as an integer, it gets wrapped modulo `2**32` to give `-2**31` instead of `2**31`.

In contrast, the nearest single-precision float to `2147483583` is `2147483520.0`, which *does* fit in a 32-bit integer.